# Object to json convertion format using serializer

Tags: c#, json

I have the following c# model object

```
public class AddressUserFields
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string apartment { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public string DPV { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to convert it to json string using json serialization method, it will convert like the following,

JSON string: `{userFields:[{"number":null,"street":null,"apartment":"","city":null,"state":null,"zipcode":null,"DPV":null}]}`

But actually I look for like the below,
Expected JSON result:

```
{userFields:[{"number":null},{"street":null},{"apartment":""},{"city":null},{"state":null},{"zipcode":null},{"DPV":null}]}
```

So could any one give the way to design my c# model object and get the expected json result.

Comment: the Json has to be valid first, it's not paste it here http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: check json syntax errors with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: {userFields:[{"number":null,"street":null,"apartment":"","city":null,"state":null,"zipcode":null,"DPV":null}]} consider this.

Comment: You could use `[{"number":"51"},{"street":"370 MILL VALLEY RD TRLR 33"},{"apartment":""},{"city":"YOUNG AMERICA"},{"state":"MN"},{"zipcode":"55555"},{"DPV":""}]` as output format (changed the outer **object** to an **array**)

Comment: Yes I have tried I created the list List<userFields>.  Then I added an item with list. After that I have converted but I will not give the expected result. I have used to design my c# model object using json2csharp.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to create your poco objects in the structure your want the Json to be in.

If you want this structure:

```
{userFields:
  [
   { "number":null,
     "street":null,
     "apartment":"",
     "city":null,
     "state":nul‌​l,
     "zipcode":null,
     "DPV":null
   }
  ]
 }
```

This is an object with one property `userFields` of type `AddressUserFields[]`.

So just add another class

```
public class SomeContainer
{
     public AddressUserFields[] userFields {get;set;}
}
```

and serialize that one

If you really want an array of different objects which all have different properties, like what you posted:

```
...[{"number":null},{"street":null},{"apartment":""},...]
```

you can use an array of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, like this:

```
public class Fields
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] userFields { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like so?

```
var fields = new Fields()
{
    userFields = new[]{
        new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"number", null}},
        new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"street", null}}
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);
```

Comment: This assumes having the *Newtonsoft Json* package installed

Comment: I used array dictionary... Thanks folk.. Now I can able to get the expected result. :)